# File Maker Script Relative Cell Value

Tags: script, filemaker

I'm new to FileMaker as well as Database administration in general.

In my table, every Record contains a link to an Adobe Illustrator file and two Photosho files. The layout speciies a button for each of those files for each Record. The button launches a script that would theoretically launch the Illustrator/Photoshop file that it corresponds to.

Here's the script I'm using for Illustrator:

`Send Event ["aevt"; "odoc"; test::Illustrator]`

where `test` is the name of the table and `Illustrator` is the name of the name of the column containing the Illustrator file. (That column is of type `Container`.)

So here's the problem I'm running into. Most of the time, the button doesn't work. It gives me an error that says, "The file "blah blah.ai" could not be found and is required to complete this operation."

When it *does* work, it is immediately after reassigning the file in the`Illustrator` cell. In that case, the specific Record that I most recently assigned works and all the others are broken. This leads me to wonder if the script I'm using is considering `Illustrator` relatively to the current Record. Do I need to explicitly specify that? Does anybody know what I'm missing?

EDIT: It seems that the problem actually arises when all the referenced files are *not* in the same folder.

Comment: Hi @Grant! Nothing wrong with your question in particular. We don't really have specialty in FileMaker here and it would most likely be answered better on SuperUser.